# SQL ordinal concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation, ordinal

I have a table, looks like this.

```
Product ID | Description  | Order
100             | This is a       | 1
100             | for test         | 3
100             | Description | 2 
101             | Product 101| 1
406             | here              | 2
406             | Enter desc   | 1
```

I need to have t-sql logic to concatenate and group the description for each unique product ID as dictated by the order number.

Output should look like this:

```
Product ID| Description
100            | This is a Description for test
101            | Product 101
406            | Enter desc here
```

Need to avoid hard coded logic as the description can be extended by users in the system.

All responses will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This looks like homework. Got any attempts to show us?

Comment: Take a look at this http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation which has several options to achieve what you are after

Answer (score 0):

```
--Create Temporary Table
CREATE TABLE #Products
(
     [Product ID] INT
    ,[Description] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[Order] INT
);
GO

--Insert sample data into #Products
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (100, 'This is a', 1);
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (100, 'for test', 3);
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (100, 'Description', 2);
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (101, 'Product 101', 1);
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (406, 'here', 2);
INSERT INTO #Products ([Product ID], [Description], [Order]) VALUES (406, 'Enter desc', 1);
GO

--GROUP BY [Product ID] to concatenate [Description] in the order of [Order]
SELECT
     [Product ID]
     ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Order] = 1 THEN       [Description] ELSE NULL END),'') +
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Order] = 2 THEN ' ' + [Description] ELSE NULL END),'') +
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [Order] = 3 THEN ' ' + [Description] ELSE NULL END),'') AS [Description]
FROM #Products
GROUP BY [Product ID];
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but this was simple. I wrapped the MAX() functions with ISNULL() for cases when there was <= [Order] values.

Comment: I think you should mention that this query will concatenate only first 3 rows of Description for each Product, even if there are more rows in the table.